# Low bandwidth only on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, performance, internet, bandwidth

Hi I own really old PC and I've 10Mbps/1Mbps Plan. Internet is distibuted with router over whole house.

The old PC uses 802.11b (up to 11Mbit/s download) Wifi card and has Windows XP+SP3 installed. Measured DL/UL speed are only ~0.8Mbps/1Mbps (tested with some speedtest websites and direct downloading). But when I launch Ubuntu or other liveCD distro I get normal desired speed ~10Mbps/1Mbps.

What I tried:

- disable services: windows update, BITS, QoS
- TCPOptimizer
- increase simultaneous TCP connection limit
- reinstall Windows

Other PCs with Win7, Linux, BSD work well. Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's 1 Mbps, and not 1 MBps (or 1 MB/s)?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about Megabits per second.